# PL/SQL Statement to Return NULL when NO_RECORD_FOUND, or NULL found value in column ELSE return TO_DATE

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a case in a payroll document where the Termination Date of an Employee COULD be (null) if there is no Termination Date.  Sometimes, I got something other than a date (garbage).  Sometimes I had a bonafide termination date report.

In this case, I did not wish to write long lines of code with IF, SELECT, CASE or EXECEPTION when trying to determine whether or not there was a record found, nor if the date was garbage or not.  I just wanted a NULL or a TO_DATE.

I probably spent more time on this than it was worth, but thought I would share my findings and see what everyone thought.  I appreciate constructive criticism or improvement.

I would like however to add ' parenthesis ' around the Date when it is NOT NULL, so that I can use it in a Dynamic SQL I am writing.  ie, it would be '15-Feb-2012' or just NULL.

I'm playing with the DECODE to get that to happen now, but still figuring it out.  Ideas?

```
SELECT TO_DATE( 
    ( SELECT B FROM OUTPUT_TABLE WHERE A = 'Term Date:' AND REGEXP_LIKE(B,'?[0-9]/?[0-9]/[0-9]{4}') )
, 'mm-dd-yyyy')
AS id FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not a blog, it is for programming questions and answers and, in this case, you have not asked a question. Please [edit] the post include a question that you want assistance with (otherwise this is off-topic for site).

Comment: Stack Overflow has an option in it to clearly answer your own question and share your own answer.  It is included as a check-mark when you 'ask the question' as an option to share your knowledge.

Comment: Please read the https://stackoverflow.com/tour as it states there "Stack Overflow is a question and answer site" and "This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat. Just questions... ...and answers." Yes, self-answers to questions are encouraged but you need to ask a question first; if you are not asking a question then it is off-topic.

Comment: I had a question anyways, so I updated it.  If they don't want anyone 'answering their question' then they should remove the selection on the bottom of the question form asking if they would like to answer their own question to share their knowledge.  It is clearly there.

Comment: Yes! Stack Exchange has always explicitly encouraged users to answer their own questions. If you have a question that you already know the answer to, and you would like to document that knowledge in public so that others (including yourself) can find it later, it's perfectly okay to ask and answer your own question on a Stack Exchange site.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those with 11g or older, the old-school way before these newer enhancements came along is write a function that traps conversion errors and returns `NULL` rather than raising an exception:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_safe_to_date(in_date_string IN varchar2, in_format IN varchar2)
  RETURN date
AS
  var_date date;
BEGIN
  var_date := TO_DATE(in_date_string,in_format);
  RETURN var_date;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RETURN NULL;
END;
```

Then use it in your select statement:

```
SELECT f_safe_to_date(B, 'mm-dd-yyyy') term_date FROM OUTPUT_TABLE WHERE A = 'Term Date:'
```

Of course you can add more `REGEXP_LIKE` logic if you want to reduce unnecessary executions, but the result would be the same.

Comment: Thank you Paul.  I've saved your function in my database.  I may use it, but in any case it will be very helpful to refer back to if I need to augment or use it in another case.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using PL/SQL then from Oracle 12, you can use:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_b output_table.b%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT b
  INTO   v_b
  FROM   OUTPUT_TABLE
  WHERE  A = 'Term Date:'
  AND    VALIDATE_CONVERSION(B AS DATE, 'mm-dd-yyyy') = 1;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_b);
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Does not exist or is not a valid date.');
END;
/
```

If you just want a couple of lines of SQL:

```sql
SELECT ( SELECT TO_DATE(b DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR, 'mm-dd-yyyy')
         FROM   output_table
         WHERE  a = 'Term Date:' ) AS b
FROM   DUAL;
```

Comment: This is very good code.  Not sure why your answer disappeared for a moment.  I've found it very useful and learning and decided to use it, and thank you.

Comment: @Stephen-Developer I deleted it when I realised that you had not asked a question. I undeleted it when you plagiarised it and copied it into your second answer.

Comment: I gave you the credit for it, so it isn't plagiarism.  I just didn't know who wrote it, so I couldn't name you.  It is very good code and should be shared, which is why I re-posted it (and thanked whoever wrote it).  I'm happy to delete my answer since you put it back up

Comment: I just tried running this one on the PAYROLL table which has many more entries in it database, and it gave me the error ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row.

Comment: @Stephen-Developer Yes, it will do if you have multiple rows that match `a = 'Term Date:'`. However, you have not provided a [MRE] and have exactly the same issue with the code in your answer so I do not see how we can provide you with a better solution if you have not described the data you are trying to process, the output you expect for that input data and we are only able to work blindly from your code.

Comment: fyi, I used this one in the PROCEDURE I needed it for.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TO_DATE( 
    ( SELECT B FROM OUTPUT_TABLE WHERE A = 'Term Date:' AND REGEXP_LIKE(B,'?[0-9]/?[0-9]/[0-9]{4}') )
, 'mm-dd-yyyy')
AS id FROM DUAL;
```

Breaking it down, today I learned:

1. There is a 'Dummy Table' in Oracle called DUAL which will return (null) when there is no record found.  But will return the actual value sought when the record is found.
2. There is a COALESCE that I can use to test for NULL.  [IS_NULL is easier to remember, but apparently ORACLE wanted COALESCE instead].  I toyed with this also, but have removed it for the above statement.
3. There is a REGEX_LIKE that I can use to test for valid values, using regular expressions.
4. I can sum it all up into another function like TO_DATE().
5. There is also a DECODE function I tried, but decided not to use.  I was very excited to learn this could be used as a TERNARY (IF WHEN ELSE) selector too.

I hope someone finds this useful and/or if I made a mistake or there could be an improvement, feel free to chime in.

Comment: There is lots wrong with this. The `DUAL` table will not "return `NULL` when no record is found" as the `DUAL` table is a table with a single column `DUMMY` and a single row with the value `'X'`; the `NULL` is being implicitly generated in place of the `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception in the sub-query and is being returned from the `TO_DATE` function. `COALESCE` is part of the ANSI SQL standard and is nothing to do with "what Oracle wanted"; `IS_NULL` and `DECODE` are not in the ANSI standard.